# How to run multiple query/update calls as part of the same transaction with Spring's JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm writing my own `DAO` layer with Spring JDBC.
I have a method called `T insert(T entity);` which inserts an entity and returns the updated version to the user. In my code, the logic is made up of two parts, a call to `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update` to save the entity and then `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject` to retrieve the updated entity from the database.

The first part executes a query similar to this:

```sql
INSERT INTO client (email_address, company_name)
VALUES ('some@email.com', 'some company name');
```

And the second part executes one similar to this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM client t
WHERE t.id = currval('client_id_seq');
```

I'm using Postgres, where `client` is actually an updatable view, not a table, and `client_id_seq` is a manually defined sequence to make `client` behave like a table.

And it works fine, except for the fact that those two statements aren't transactional. In theory, between the time of executing the first and second statement, another parallel statement could be executed, which alters `currval('client_id_seq')`, making the result of the second part of my method erroneous.

Is there a way of executing and fetching data all at once with Spring Jdbc? I tried multi-statement queries and the driver complained that there are multiple `ResultSet`s, I also tried writing a transaction query like this:

```sql
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO client (email_address, company_name)
VALUES ('some@email.com', 'some company name');

SELECT * FROM client t
WHERE t.id = currval('client_id_seq');

COMMIT;
```

And the driver complained that the `ResultSet` was null.

How do I ensure consistency here between these two fetches?

#### EDIT:

If I am understanding [@Mar-Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14294053/mar-z)'s answer correctly, if the value of `client_id_seq` is 0, and SESSION 1 calls `nextval('client_id_seq')`, then SESSION 2 calls `nextval('client_id_seq')`, the ACTUAL value of `client_id_seq` is now 2. BUT, if I call `currval('client_id_seq')` in SESSION 1, I'll get back 1, and if I call `currval('client_id_seq')` in SESSION 2, I'll get back a 2. That seems promising.

The only other thing I might be worried about is, I know that Spring Boot uses a connection pool (HikariCP by default I think), and 1 authenticated connection = 1 postgres session. Could it be possible that, lets say we have some connection `SESS_1` in the connection pool. The first `update` call to insert the `client` is submitted to the DB via `SESS_1`. INBETWEEN the first and second call of my `insert()` method, another process also submits some query to the DB via `SESS_1`, hence altering the `currval('client_id_seq')` for `SESS_1`, and then the second part of my method runs the `SELECT` query, again, on `SESS_1`, so in the end, I have erroneous data. Or even worse, what if the connection pool decides to close `SESS_1` and supply a different connection, say `SESS_2`, to the second part of my `insert()` method?

Does Spring JDBC have some things to assure this doesn't happen? Do I need to configure anything?

#### EDIT 2

When marking a method with `@Transactional`, Spring Boot binds the connection to the thread which is running the method, and only releases the connection back to the pool when the transaction completes or is reversed. So in theory, annotating my `insert()` method with `@Transactional` should guarantee data consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about transactions and parallel changes to the sequence. With the call of ***currval('client_id_seq')*** you will get exactly the value of the sequence which has been obtained with *nextval('client_id_seq')* in **YOUR** current session only. Other sessions will use different value. This is garrantied by the database.

More details here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

Comment: I couldn't fit my comment here, so I edited my question instead. Thanks